# Update Table with subform values

Tags: ms-access

apologize for bad English grammar: it's a book sale database, I have some problems with update "inventory" field - from books (book_id, price, inventory) table - values in "sale" form, there is sub form about how much a kind of book sold (book_id, qty) in "sale" form.
please help, thanks

Comment: Ok, so you have a form "Sale" and a sub form called "?".  What is the problem you are having?  And how are you trying to populate the subform?

Comment: Your English is better than my non-English.  :o)  But I still don't understand what you're asking?  Are you trying to update "inventory" in books table with "qty" in books sold table?

Comment: sub form called "sale_details" - book_id, qty. for example the inventory of "book1" is 100 and "book2" is 200, I sold 20 from "book1" and 10 from "book2" to "customer1", then my inventory going to be like this: "book1" 80 and "book2" is 190 _ @milad moafi

Comment: That's doable, but do you want to add a new record each time with a running total?  Or do you want to keep a single record for each book and modify/edit that single record each time?

Comment: want to keep a single record for each book and modify/edit that single record each time @milad moafi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

If you want to edit a record, you would do something like this:

```
'this will create the recordset variable and a string variable
Dim myR As Recordset
Dim strSQL as String    

'to find the record you want to edit use this and then set your recordset to this query
strSQL = "Select * From Books Where book_id = '" & Me.Book_I_Want_To_Edit_Field & "'"

'make the table strSQL your table to work with
Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)


'you can set your subform fields or controls here
Me.Sales_Details.Form.Field_in_subform_to_edit = MyR![Inventory]

'you need this to edit it
myR.Edit

'Modify everything here with vba

'then update it
myR.Update

'clear the variable
Set myR = Nothing
```

Let me know if something like this will help or if you need me to update it.

Comment: I know how to update a field, add some records, execute SQL and ... with VBA, but I can't write that SQL query - @milad Moafi